# ¿Cómo puedo iniciar un proyecto de nodejs con babel?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, aws

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto simple en Nodejs con ECMAScript 6, las pruebas de inicio del servidor las hice usando nodemon y funcionaba correctamente. Este es el comando que estaba utilizando. `dev": "nodemon index.js --exec babel-node"`, pero quiero desplegar el proyecto en aws y este es el comando que necesito para hacerlo: `"start": "node index.js"`. Pero me genera el siguiente error al no reconocer babel.

```
(node:3496) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
C:\Users\eospi\Documents\webappbackend\index.js:1
import express from 'express';
```

Esta es las estructura de mi archivo **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "sistema",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-promise-router": "^3.0.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.10",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.7",
    "@babel/register": "^7.7.7",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

Comment: Al parecer el error se debe a que estas importando el módulo express con `import express from 'express'` cuando debería ser `const express = require('express')`

Comment: Babel lo que hace es compilar tu codigo es6 a es5 para tener compatibilidad con navegadores y codigo "antiguo". Para el caso de express lo primero que tienes que correr es el modulo de babel (el compilador) y que genere todo el codigo como es5.

Comment: Intenta algo asi `"node_modules/.bin/nodemon app.js --exec babel-node --"`